# print excel form with different content

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba macro for printing a form (in one worksheet) populated with data (from other worksheet), does anybody know how to do several printouts of the same form in a single print job, actually it is printing a different job each time with a large delay between jobs. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post vba macro to clarify your question.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=someNumber`?

Comment: Dim count As Long
Dim Cant As Long
'
Worksheets("Datos").Activate
count = 1
Cant = Cells(2, "T").Value


Do While count <= Cant
    Worksheets(2).Range("a13").Value = count
    Worksheets(2).Range("a14").Value = count + 1
    count = count + 2
Worksheets(1).Activate
    
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "recibos"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Worksheets(1).Activate
Loop
Worksheets("Datos").Activate
End Sub

Comment: i have 2 forms per page

Comment: in worksheet(1) I fill the form, in worksheet(2) i have the data i use to fill that form and count selects the row of data to use